# Cannot estimate gas for transfer function

Tags: solidity, gas, ethers.js

When I want to call a transfer function from my smart contract deployed on Rinkeby, I get the next error: `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`
This is how my Solidity tranfer function looks:

```
function transfer(address payable _to, uint _amount) public payable {
        (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    }
```

And this is how I call it with ethers.js in my React app:

```
const transfer = async () => {
        let amount = listing.offer ? listing.discountedPrice : listing.regularPrice
        amount = ethers.utils.parseEther(amount)
        await contract.transfer(listing.ethereumAddress, amount)
        console.log('Transfer was successful')
    }
```

Can somebody help me, please? I did not find any answers for this yet.

Comment: Did you tried adding a manual gas limit?

Comment: Adding await contract.transfer(listing.ethereumAddress, amount, {gasLimit: 30000}) is working. But the problem is that I don't know how to convert from wei to ether

Comment: you are already doing it, this ´ethers.utils.parseEther(amount)´turns ether units into Wei units